# how to convert H(b < g) = 2*100 - H(b < g) from MATLAB to python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I have the MATLAB code like below

```matlab
H = [10 20 30 40 50 60]
b = [5 9 28 59 22 18]
g = [9 9 10 25 30 5]

H(b < g) = 2*100 - H(b < g)
```

the result is like this :

```
H = 
    190    20    30    40    150    60
```

I think this code means that if `b[index] < g[index]` then `H[index] = 2*100 - H[index]`

Is my understanding is correct?
Is there way in python to do it without looping for the index?

Comment: Same thing but swap the parentheses for brackets.

Comment: Your supposition would not lead to that output.

Comment: Are you using NumPy in Python? If not, you should. Then @OriYarden's comment above applies. NumPy makes translating from MATLAB quite straight-forward.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes i'm already using numpy,  thankyouu

Comment: The python libraries NumPY and the higher level library Pandas are used for doing mathematical operations very quickly on lists of data with each other. They are very feature rich and have a huge user base. But if you don't need efficiency you can do it in standard python but it will always use a loop either explicitly or under the hood.

Comment: @JorgeLuis sorry, do you mean there is another meaning of the function? can you tell me please? because i'm new in this..

Comment: @AndrewAllaire thankyou for the advice, i need to use it for image preprocessing

Comment: @KEZIAANGELINE What I mean is that the lists your provided don't lead to that result. Instead final `H` would be: `190 20 30 40 150 60`.

Comment: @JorgeLuis oh thankyou, i'm so sorry, i didn't realize that i copy the wrong result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the code is correct: the MATLAB code checks which elements of `b` are less than the corresponding element of `g`, and changes only those corresponding elements of `H` to `200 - H`.

Since you're [already using `numpy`](/questions/75735799/how-to-convert-hb-g-2100-hb-g-from-matlab-to-python/75736133#comment133604225_75735799), translating MATLAB is quite straightforward: just change the parentheses to brackets.

```
H = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
b = np.array([5, 9, 28, 59, 22, 18])
g = np.array([9, 9, 10, 25, 30, 5])

H[b < g] = 2*100 - H[b < g]
```

Which gives the desired `H`:

```
array([190,  20,  30,  40, 150,  60])
```

Here's a handy resource for translating MATLAB to numpy: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Answer (score 2):

To make it in just one line.
If `b` or `g` are too short, this code will raise an exception.

```
H = [2*100 - h if b[inx] < g[inx] else h
     for inx, h in enumerate(H)]
```

As have already been said in the comments, if you have a lot of code from Matlab to "translate" into Python, you better use `numpy`.

Comment: You could also use `zip`: `H = [2 * 100 - hh if bb < gg else hh for hh, bb, gg in zip(h, b, g)]`